# Find current running Url or Tab in chrome using Python in windows platform

Tags: python, windows, selenium, google-chrome, automation

I want to know that is there any possible way to get the current working URL in Google Chrome.

I tried using **selenium, pywinauto** libraries in python, but couldn't get the expected output.

In selenium:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager.install())
print(driver.current_url())
```

but it gives a syntax error

```
from webdriver_manager.driver import ChromeDriver
self.auth_header = {'Authorization': f'token {self._os_token}'}
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My working platform is 64bit windows10, python 3.5. Hope will get the answer. Thanks

Comment: you can use `browser.current_url`.

Comment: @BhargavDesai , give more details if you know.

Answer (score 0):

### current_url

[`current_url`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_url) is a property which gets the URL of the current page.

---

### Solution

So instead of:

```
print(driver.current_url())
```

You need to:

```
print(driver.current_url)
```

---

### This usecase

To extract the `current_url` first you need to invoke the *url* through get and then retrieve the *url* as follows:

```
get("https://www.google.com/")
print(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: it is not working for me. the solution you did mention above gives new chrome window only not the url

Comment: @Mathan You haven't invoked the `get(url)` yet, hence as per your current code you would see the output as `data;`

Comment: .so i have to give the url link  in the beginning?